List of Second Temple Rabbis
Is there a list of all of the rabbis during the second temple period?
Pirkei Avot lists the men of the great assembly, followed by Shimon haTzadik.  The problem is that there are at least three different people that this Shimon could be and from what I could find, traditional sources list him as synonymous with one of the other two.  There is Shimon haMacabee, there's Shimon the high priest who met Alexander, and there is the Shimon of Pirkei Avot.  Unfortunately, there are some sources mentioning Antigonus (his disciple) living in the second century BCE, and others saying he lived in the 4th century BCE.  If it was the former, then the identification of Shimon with Shimon haMacabee seems to be correct, but then we don't know the chain of descent from the men of the great assembly to Shimon.  This theory also goes against the common view that the nassi at the time of the chanukkah story was Yossi ben Yoezer.  The other theory, identifying Shimon HaTzadik with the Shimon that met Alexander, also doesn't make sense because then there's not enough generations in Pirkei Avot between him and Yossi ben Yoezer, and also still doesn't fix the issue of us not knowing who his teacher was, because Pirkei Avot says that he was the last of the Great Assembly, but if so, then he would have been a contemporary of Ezra, who lived around 200 years before (temple being built in the late 500s BCE).
Are there any sources that perhaps mention the Great Assembly lasting for multiple generations or around 200 years?  If not, and the sources say that the Great Assembly was a one-generation thing, how do we account for the gap in time and the inconsistency of who Shimon haTzadik is?
I am aware that there is a differing chronology between the Seder Olam Rabbah and the archeological evidence, and I think that the conventional chronology makes more sense (Seder Olam can be interpreted non-literally, so meshing the two isn't an issue for me), so how do we account for a seeming glaring gap in teachers?
Edit: I also came across an opinion by Rabbi Ishmael that there was roughly 700 years between the destructions of the temples, which seems to line up more with the conventional chronology, but Rabbi Ishmael doesn't break down how he calculated everything and who the leaders in each generation were, so we still have the same issue I asked about above.

All the rabbis in the Gemora are listed in the Seder haDoros by R. Heilprin, the 1st folume describes events chronologically. The second volume is called Seder Tanaim and Amoraim and gives information about them alphabetically. One needs to sift the info from both volumes.

Also Maseches Chagiga 2.2 gives the list of nasiim and avos beis din https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Chagigah.2.2?lang=bi

In Jewish tradition Shimon Ha'tzaddik has always been identified as the Kohen Gadol who lived during the Greco-Macedonian conquest. He is the same one mentioned in the beginning of Avot, and has never been identified with any later Shimon. The same is true for Antigonos, though if you think there's an actual traditional source that shows that he lived in the 2nd century, please cite it in your question. The suggestions for identifying Shimon Ha'tzaddik with later figures are largely modern academic suggestions, although Josephus is also iffy about the topic.
